# What does this weird notation mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

```
var names = [name for(name in generateNames(product))];
```

`generateNames` just returns an array of column names for various properties in a product.

But what is the whole name for name in thing?

Comment: That looks like a syntax error to me (Unexpected token for).

Comment: Thats what my professor gave us: the function should be callable as: var names = [name for (name in generateNames(product))]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an [array comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Array_comprehensions_%28Merge_into_Array_comprehensions%29).

It's a new feature of Javascript 1.7, and works like Python's [list comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Comment: So if I have something like: var names = [name for (name in generateNames(product))]...then what is the point of doing this...array comprehension?

Comment: As it is, the code doesn't really benefit from the array comprehension (you could just write `var names = generateNames(product);`). I suspect that's only an example though. Comprehensions are useful if your want to project each item from the original array, or add a condition, like e.g. `var names = [returnSomethingFrom(name) for (name in generateNames(product)) if (name !== "")];`.

Comment: Aha! Makes sense. So you can add conditionals. What about actual calculations? Is there a way to do that? Like say I had an array [1,2,3] and I wanted to get the largest number from the array, would I be able to include that somehow as a condition?

Comment: Probably not, getting the largest number from an array is an aggregate operation, and evaluating a conditional on each item won't help much with that.

Answer (score 4):

It is an array comprehension.  It was added to JavaScript 1.7.  Works only in Mozilla browsers like Firefox AFAIK.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Array_comprehensions_(Merge_into_Array_comprehensions)

Here is a jsfiddle you can try, in Firefox only: http://jsfiddle.net/hfARW/1/

Comment: Ah ha! Bleeding edge stuff that is a syntax error in most browsers … so I was half right :)

Comment: JavaScript 1.6, 1.7, 1.8. and 1.9 have a lot of experimental stuff that is not even going to make it into ECMAScript 6.  A lot of it *is* in ECMAScript 5, but a lot of it is Mozilla's playground.  Real comprehensions are in CoffeeScript and Python. :)  John Resig has a little post on [versions of JS](http://ejohn.org/blog/versions-of-javascript/) you might find interesting.